# What is the status of gauged gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, quantum-gravity

The Standard Model of elementary particles is a gauge theory with gauge group $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$, which is really a successful theory.

We might be able to quantize gravity similarly. Gravity might be treated as a force, instead of spacetime curve as in general relativity. I know little about gauged gravity theory. What is the current status? Who are working on it? Is it really worthwhile to pursue now?